# Pandas join vs add column

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have 2 dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) with the same `MultiIndex`. `df1` has column A, `df2` has column B.

I found 2 ways of 'joining' these dataframes:

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, how='inner')
```

or

```
df1['B'] = df2['B']
```

First option takes much longer. Why? 
Does option 2 not look at indexes and just 'attaches' the column to the right?

Running this afterwards returns `True`, so the end result is the same it seems, but perhaps this is because the indexes in `df1` and `df2` are also in the same order:

```
df_joined.equals(df1)
```

Is there any faster way to join the dataframes knowing the indexes are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no faster way than `df1['B'] = df2['B']` if indices are aligned.

Assigning a series to another series is already well optimised in `pandas`.

`join` takes longer than assignment as it explicitly lines up `df1.index` and `df2.index`, which is expensive. It is not assumed that indices are in consistent order. As per [pd.DataFrame.join documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), if no column is specified the `join` will take place on the dataframes' respective indices.

I would be surprised if you find this is a bottleneck in your workflow. If it is, then I suggest you drop down to `numpy` arrays and avoid `pandas` altogether.

Comment: The OP doesn't complain about the execution speed of `df1['B'] = df2['B']`, but instead curious about why the `join` method takes much longer then the assignment?

Comment: @Szabolcs added a short explanation.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis so what would happen if the index in df2 was in a different order, i.e. miss-aligned? In `df1['B'] = df2['B']`, the column would still be added but it would be inherently wrong, i.e. values at the wrong indices?

Comment: @Dimebag, `pandas` will line up the series accordingly, e.g. index 0 from `df2` will be assigned to index 0 from `df1`, even if they are in different ordinal positions when you `print` the dataframe. I don't know if it's index or ordinal position that matters in your case.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis so if the indices are not aligned, the worst case performance of `df1['B'] = df2['B']` is the same as `df1.join(df2)`, correct?

Comment: Short answer, the logic used is completely different. `df1.join(df2)` does a lot more and will always be slower, even if output is identical. You can look at the `pandas` source code for more details.