# Python/Pandas - If last X instances = 0 then Y

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe that has user IDs, which week they've logged on and how many sessions they had during that week. It looks similar to this:

| ID | Week | Sessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 0 |

I am looking to find out if a user has churned. Churn here is if in the last 3 weeks of a user's lifetime, they haven't had any session. In the example above it means that only user 3 churned (as the first user had a session at their last week).

Ideally the dataframe would look like this:

| ID | Week | Sessions | Churn Session | Churned_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

How can I replicate the above?

Thank you.

Comment: So you only really care about the last three records for each ID, correct? Also does each ID have at least three records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a case for *.groupby(['ID'])['Sessions'].rolling(3).sum()*  as described in [How to perform rolling sum on pandas dataframe with group by for last 365 days only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63539146/149076)

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the last 3 session records of each user ID then if the sum is 0 keep the user:

```
is_churned = lambda x: x.iloc[-3:].sum() == 0
out = df[df.groupby('ID')['Sessions'].transform(is_churned)]
print(out)

# Output
    ID  Week  Sessions
13   3     1         8
14   3     2         2
15   3     3         0
16   3     4         0
17   3     5         0
18   3     6         0
19   3     7         0
```